# RestSharp library not found when running csc

Tags: c#, .net-core, restsharp

I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;

namespace MyProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new RestClient
            {
                BaseUrl = new Uri("www.newuri.com"),
                Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username: "myusername", password: "mypassword")
            };

            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

            var response = client.Execute(request);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm coding using VS2017 and this program compiles perfectly on it. The problem is that I want to compile and run it via Command Prompt and when I try to run command:

```
csc Program.cs
```

I'm getting error:

> Program.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RestSharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   Program.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RestSharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Am I missing something when compiling via CMD?

Comment: The question's title and the problem are not the same. You are not even using ASP.NET Core in this question. It doesn't compile because Program.cs does not have the RestSharp library built in

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto sorry for inappropriate question. Could you please explain me how should I build in the library?

Answer (score 0):

If you compile with `csc`, you will need to manually specify the paths to all your references.

Few people compile by manually invoking `csc`. Instead, they use build software which understands the `csproj` file format and runs `csc` for them.

Can you try running `msbuild` or `dotnet build`? That will respect all your references you've added in Visual Studio.

Comment: @NikasŽalias: Well maybe you should provide more information then.

Comment: Did you try running `msbuild` or `dotnet build`? What error message did you get?